# Use PowerShell to merge .reg file with Windows registry

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

Running any of the below commands doesn't produce the intended result of showing the navigation pane in Windows Explorer.

GUI way that works:
Right-click on the .reg file and select Merge. If prompted by UAC, click on Yes.
Click on Yes to confirm that you want to add the registry keys.

Contents of shownavigationpane.reg:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\GlobalSettings\Sizer] "PageSpaceControlSizer"=hex:a0,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,56,05,00,00`

I've tried the below 5 PowerShell commands seperatly preceded by Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted and none of them have produced the intended result. I have ran the commands with Windows explorer closed.

1. `reg import c:\ps\shownavigationpane.reg`
2. `start-process reg -ArgumentList "import C:\temp\shownavigationpane.reg"`
3. `regedit /s "C:\temp\shownavigationpane.reg"`
4. `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {reg import c:\temp\shownavigationpane.reg}`
5. `Start-Process -filepath "C:\windows\regedit.exe" -argumentlist "/s c:\temp\shownavigationpane.reg"`

Comment: Does it work if you run PowerShell as administrator? `Set-ExecutionPolicy` should not affect ability to import to the registry.

Comment: `regedit.exe` should be under `c:\windows\system32` . Not `C:\windows\` . Also, you are trying to import the key under Current user. So, whatever account you are running the script as will put that key under their hive.

Comment: I am running PowerShell as administrator. I am finding regedit.exe within c:\windows\ . I have tried again to run each of the five lines separately with Windows Explorer closed and none of them are producing the intended result of showing the navigation pane in Windows Explorer

Comment: It worked successfully on a different Windows 10 computer. The issue must have to do with the user account, like jrider has commented. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [jrider's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69396461/use-powershell-to-merge-reg-file-with-windows-registry#comment122657881_69396461) but like to offer an alternative solution

If that is the only setting you would like to change in the registry, you can do this straight from within PowerShell:

```
$regPath = 'Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\GlobalSettings\Sizer'
# if that registry path does not already exist, create it here
$null = New-Item -Path $regPath -Force

$values = [byte[]](0xa0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x56, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00)
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name 'PageSpaceControlSizer' -Value $values -Type Binary -Force
```